# Error response from daemon: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): unexpected EOF

Tags: docker

I am importing a file named myimage.xz into docker but i run into said error.
i ran the following command and then got the error

Command:

```
cat myimage.xz | docker import - mydockerimage
```

I ran this command with and without sudo.
Anyways I got the following error

```
Error response from daemon: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): unexpected EOF
```

Comment: Do you get any errors if you run `xz -t myimage.xz`?

Comment: I have no clue what this is how can i run it?

Comment: This gives the following erro

Comment: xz: myimage.xz: Compressed data is corrupt

Comment: If the image file is corrupt, then the error is in how it was created or in how it was sent to the machine you're trying to import it on.

Comment: In normal use you don't use `docker import` at all.  What produced the `.xz` file; can you provide a [mcve], including the relevant application code?  (If it's not a programming question, a different Stack Exchange site may be a more appropriate place to ask.)